# Grep to exclude comment like -- with trailing spaces

Tags: bash, grep

I have the regex:

```
grep -iE 'UTL_FILE[\. ]*(FCOPY|FGETATTR|FOPEN|FOPEN_NCHAR|FREMOVE|FRENAME|fopen)'
```

And I would like to extend it to exclude all the lines which are comments starting with any number of withe spaces and '--'

For example, get the next line (This is already done by the regular expression):

```
 l_output := utl_file.fopen(p_RutaLocal, Nombre_Archivo,'w');
```

But ignore lines like this:

```
 --l_output := utl_file.fopen(p_RutaLocal, Nombre_Archivo,'w'); or
       --  l_output := utl_file.fopen(p_RutaLocal, Nombre_Archivo,'w');
```

Comment: please update the question with a sample of 5-10 input lines (some with and without comments, some with and without the desired string matches) and the expected output (corresponding to the provided sample input)

Answer (score 2):

Pipe two greps together:

```sh
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*--' | grep -iE ...
```

The `-v` option prints lines that *don't* match.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to try:

```
 grep -Ev "^[[:space:]]*--"|grep -iE 'UTL_FILE[\. ]*(FCOPY|FGETATTR|FOPEN|FOPEN_NCHAR|FREMOVE|FRENAME|fopen)'
```